# concatinating int[] to same size string[]

Tags: c#, .net

i have:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3};
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

and need the output to be

```
1=one
2=two
3=three
```

thanks

Comment: Oh, come on. The straightforward solution is extremely trivial if you know the necessary stuff - and if you don't, you should be learning about it with a book and/or teacher instead of asking us for the solution.

Comment: @delnan - We all have to learn somewhere. If we all knew the answers to everything then Stack Overflow would have no reason to exist.

Comment: @Andrew: Of course. And that includes beginner questions. However, I read this question as "plz gimme teh codez for this simple thing I'm supposed to do but can't be bothered to or don't understand", and if that's the case, giving out a solution (especially one using relatively advanced concepts such as LINQ) doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @ Andrew: Sorry, but why have you removed your answer? Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: @Homam - Nothing wrong! @mBotros had the same answer as me but he was faster. :)

Comment: @delnan - It could definitely be perceived that way but unfortunately ridiculing the OP doesn't help anyone either. I didn't see anything wrong with this question and now anyone who thinks about zipping two sequences as "concatenation" will be able to find this answer, learn the proper solution, and also learn the proper terminology. Maybe instead of telling people to find a book or a teacher we should strive to *be* the book or the teacher. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if they are the same size you can use

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3};
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

var list = numbers.Zip (words, (n, w) => n + "=" + w);
```

but note if they differ in size the non match items will be ignored

Answer (score 6):

I see that everybody is jumping to Linq or IEnumerable extensions when you don't grasp the basics. It will be like putting a child to college so I suggest you first learn using loops, like the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}-{1}", numbers[i], words[i]));
}
```

And Math class basics

```
int total = Math.Min(numbers.Length, word.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
```

Comment: Now this is the straightforward solution I was talking about! Agreed, +1.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ example:

```
var query = numbers.Select((n, i) => string.Format("{0}={1}", n, words[i]));
```

**Edit:**

In .NET 4.0 you can use `Zip` (as posted by [mBotros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841335/concatinating-int-to-same-size-string/5841350#5841350)) - there's even almost same example as what you're asking for on [Zip MSDN doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

Comment: I think `Zip` extension is much better than this.

Comment: @Homam: I agree, however since `Zip` is .NET 4 child, I decided to leave this answer as well, .NET 3.5 is still quite popular :)

Comment: @ jimmy_keen: I would agree and +1.

Comment: Pardon me gents for ignorance, but in this example, why does 'i' in yield a sequence from 0,1,2 etc? I would have used "words[n-1]"  but accept that this is less elegant. Just curious. :-)

Comment: @Ron Weston: `i` stands for element index in `numbers` sequence, while `n` is value at this index. For each element at index `i` in first sequence, we also grab element at same index in second sequence and merge them together. Perhaps it would be more obvious if I wrote `numbers.Select((value, index) => /* ... */ );`

Comment: Cheers @jimmy_keen. I think what threw me is that the .Select() signature in the example apprears to match Func<int, TResult> and I couldn't see how TResult is the index....?

Comment: @Ron Weston: actually, overload I used takes `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` - but yes, when `TSource` is also `int` (as in our case) it's easy to confuse what goes where when you add index (which is int too) into the mix. Rule of thumb: whenever you can, use `Zip` instead :)

Comment: Yeah, I hear that thanks. Func always throws me off just the way it apprears in intellisense and that you have to factor in that what appears to be the last input parm is in fact the return. Thanks again @jimmy_keen